# display none if php function is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I have a wordpress function that displays adverts every so often. When are not shown essentially I would prefer to the div to display:none;

I can not seem to figure out the correct PHP function in order for the div not to display when a advert is uploaded.

```
<div class="advert" <?php if(!empty($_GET['details'])) {echo "style='display: none'";} ?>></div>
```

Comment: So the adverts depends on a url parameter to be set?

Comment: @Mike I tried this initially and it didn't work

Comment: why not `<div class="advert" <?php if(empty($_GET['details'])) {echo "style='display: none'";} ?>></div>` ?

Comment: it should be empty() instead of ! empty(), shouldn't it?

Comment: How do you determine the state for "do not display an ad"? Are you sure that you only want to check for a URL parameter?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with URL parameters is about displaying a div tag in the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not completely not echo "advert" element?

```
   if ( !empty($_GET['details']) ){
       echo '<div class="advert">add text</div>';
    }
```

if you really want to just hide, you can assign hide class

```
<div class="advert <?php echo ( empty($_GET['details'])? 'hide' : '' );">add text</div>
```

then you would need to add "hide" class with display:none in your style.css

Above is [shorthand/ternary if/else statement](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) used, its great if you need output some string.

And, please don't output/trust any user input i.e. $_GET['details'] 'as is' anywhere without escaping it, for security reasons.

Wordpress have plenty easy-to-use escape functions, like [esc_attr()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) and [esc_html()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

```
<?php
$advert_display_string = "";
if (!isset($_GET['details'])) {
    $advert_display_string = "style='display: none'";
}
?>

<div class="advert" <?php echo $advert_display_string ; ?> ></div>`
```

but having said that, instead of displaying it and then hiding it with css, you could just choose only to display it if you need it there, like below

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['details'])) {
?>
    <div class="advert"></div>
<?
}
?>
```